# PYTHON smtplib MIMEText HTML - large email text, words broken/spaces in middle

Tags: python, smtplib

I have a PYTHON script that sends emails in HTML format and I am seeing words being broken (not hyphenated) / with spaces in them. The email text is very lengthy (> 2,000 characters) and this may be the root cause, in which case, how do I get around this?

**Example Text 1:**
Once upon a time there was a developer

**Email Text 1:**
Once upon a ti me there was a developer

**Example Text 2:**
Who just couldn't figure out why

**Email Text 2:**
Who ju st couldn't fi gure out why
*(notice that 2 words are broken)*

```
msgText = MIMEText(myText, 'html')
```

Another example is where I have  in the email text and it just so happens that the space is inserted between "<" and "a", to the resultant email has the following displayed:

**Services IC Plan < a href=" https://......**

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate and an old post, but it took me a while to find an easy, straightforward answer.  Forcing utf-8 encoding solves the issue:

```
msgText = MIMEText(myText, 'html', 'utf-8')
```

See https://bugs.python.org/issue25948 for more info.